# What does netloc mean?

Tags: python, networking, flask, flask-login

I'm learning to make login function with **Flask-login**, and I'm facing with this code in my tutorial that I'm following:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '': # what is it means in this line..?
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

But I'm not sure what's the code above that I commented means..?, especially in **netloc** word, what is that..?, I know that is stand for **network locality**, but what is the purpose on that line..?

Comment: Although the function you are calling is from werkzeug. You can probably look to the standard library for the definition of netloc. See [urllib.parse.urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse). netloc is the name of the server (ip address or host name).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

From [`RFC 1808, Section 2.1`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808.html#section-2.1), every URL should follow a specific format:

```
<scheme>://<netloc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
```

Lets break this format down syntactically:

- `scheme`: The protocol name (which you'll usually see as http/https)
- `netloc`: Contains the **net**work **loc**ation - which includes the domain itself (and subdomain if present), the port number, along with an optional credentials in form of `username:password`. Together it may take form of `username:password@example.com:80`.
- `path`: Contains information on how the specified resource needs to be accessed.
- `params`: Element which adds fine tuning to path. (optional)
- `query`: Another element adding fine grained access to the path in consideration. (optional)
- `fragment`: Contains bits of information of the resource being accessed within the path. (optional)

Lets take a very simple example to understand the above clearly:

```
https://cat.example/list;meow?breed=siberian#pawsize
```

In the above example:

- `https` is the scheme (first element of a URL)
- `cat.example` is the netloc (sits between the scheme and path)
- `/list` is the path (between the netloc and params)
- `meow` is the param (sits between path and query)
- `breed=siberian` is the query (between the fragment and params)
- `pawsize` is the fragment (last element of a URL)

This can be replicated programmatically using Python's [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> url ='https://cat.example/list;meow?breed=siberian#pawsize'
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='cat.example', path='/list', params='meow', query='breed=siberian', fragment='pawsize')
```

Now coming to your code, the `if` statement checks whether or not the `next_page` exists and whether the `next_page` has a netloc. In that `login()` function, checking if `.netloc != ''`, means that it is checking whether the result of `url_parse(next_page)` is a relative URL. A relative URL has a path but no hostname (and thus no `netloc`).

Comment: In RFC 1808 Section 2.1, `net_loc` stands for `network location`, and represents: the (optional) login information, the hostname, and the (optional) port number.  According to RFC 1738 Section 3.1, this must take the form `<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>`.  This is consistent with what Python 3's documentation on `urllib.parse.urlparse`'s `ParseResult.netloc` states.  In that `login()` function, checking if `.netloc != ''`, means that it is checking whether the result of `url_parse(next_page)` is a relative url.  A relative url has a path but no hostname (and thus no `netloc`)

Comment: Any idea why it's called a netloc?

Comment: @AgentZebra See previous comment, it's a contraction of **net**work **loc**ation

Answer (score 6):

```
import urllib.parse
url="https://example.com/something?a=1&b=1"
o = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
print(o.netloc)
```

> `example.com`